# Error in sending Authorization through the header

Tags: php, android, api, rest, authorization

I'm working on a PHP Restful Api and for testing I'm using Chrome Advanced REST client and Postman, but the problem is that the api is working perfect on the localhost but on a public server when I want to send an authorization through the header, postman and advanced rest client both give me a json response including this error : "api key is missing" which means it doesn't recognize authorization!

Please take a look at these two pics:

[Authenticate function in my php rest api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vB0C2.png)

[Postman's error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4ctW.png)

Is there any solution for this problem?

I would be very grateful for any help; Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you try to print `$headers`? What's inside?

Comment: @LucaAbbati : Yes but there was everything except Authenticate :D

Comment: Please post actual code instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen due to certain Apache configurations throwing away the `Authorization` header if it's not in a known format. You could try creating a file called `.htaccess` in your applications directory, put the line `SetEnvIf Authorization (.*) HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1` in it and then access the header via `$_SERVER["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]`.

Basically, what this does is set an environment variable called `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` to whatever the value of the `Authorization` header is before Apache discards it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris :) It works perfect but with a little change: I added this line  SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1 in my .htaccess file and I used $_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] Instead of $_SERVER["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] .